# Python inner loop and outer loop with counter to iterate over list

Tags: python, for-loop

I have specific issue where, im trying to find solution on inner loop(execute 3 time) and continue outer to process rest of the list in for loop:

```
strings = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B',\
           'A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']

i=0
for string in strings:
    global i
    if string == 'A':
        while i < 3:
            print(string, i)
            i+=1
            if i==3: continue
    elif string== 'B':
         while i < 3:
            print(string,i)
            i+=1
            if i==3: continue
#         print(string)
```

Current result:
A 0
A 1
A 2

Expected to have continued over list once the inner loop complete and process from next:

```
A 0
A 1
A 2

B 0
B 1
B 2

A 0
A 1
A 2

B 0
B 1
B 2
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about what `strings` is supposed to be? There are several alternate ways to get your expected output

Comment: Replace `global i` with `i = 0`; you need to reset it per inner loop. Or just replace manual `i` management using `while` with `for i in range(3):`. Either way, get rid of `if i == 3: continue` (which accomplishes nothing).

Comment: Hi ShadownRanger,Can you explain with sample code. :strings = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B',\
           'A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']


for string in strings:
    i=0
    if string == 'A':
        while i < 3:
            print(string, i)
            i+=1
        i=0
    elif string== 'B':
         while i < 3:
            print(string,i)
            i+=1
         i=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly the logic, you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to help you form the groups:

##### variant #1

```
from itertools import groupby

MAX = 3

for k,g in groupby(strings):
    for i in range(min(len(list(g)), MAX)):
        print(f'{k} {i}')
    print()
```

##### variant #2

```
from itertools import groupby

MAX = 3

for k,g in groupby(strings):
    for i,_ in enumerate(g):
        if i >= MAX:
            break
        print(f'{k} {i}')
    print()
```

output:

```
A 0
A 1
A 2

B 0
B 1
B 2

A 0
A 1
A 2

B 0
B 1
B 2
```

##### variant #3: without import

```
prev = None
count = 0
MAX = 3
for s in strings:
    if s == prev:
        if count < MAX:
            print(f'{s} {count}')
            count += 1
    elif prev:
        count = 0
        print()
    prev = s
```

Comment: Hi Mozway, is there way to count based on, if string == 'A': count and output 3 following string and exit to continue iteration on other list?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "*other list*", maybe this should be a new question where you provide all the reproducible details?

Comment: Result is correct as expected, but as i need to check also if there is A and B only in this list. If there is anything else i need to skip the counter. As A & B is relevant not others in the given list. Sorry this is only details i can share. count only if A and B

Comment: `groupby` return the key (here `k`), you can check that `k in {'A', 'B'}` in your loop and `continue` otherwise